# Execute javascript everytime a route is hit in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When my page loads for the first time the code in /assets/javascript/home.js executes, which positions my navbar using Bootstraps affix.

```
$('.navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: function() {
      return this.bottom = $('.hero').outerHeight(true);
    }
  }
});
```

When I go to another route such as `/blog`, I don't want this code to execute and want my static CSS to render which works great. The problem is when I got back to the home route(`/`), the JavaScript doesn't execute again and my navbar is using its natural CSS. If I refresh at this point, the page will reload fully and my navbar will be positioned correctly.

I think the problem is because of turbo-links but I am not experienced enough with Rails to resolve this issue. Hope somebody can shed some light!

Comment: Found solution from this stack overflow post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links

Answer (score 0):

If you're using turbolinks, you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    // run your code
  }
});
```

Turbolinks changes the $(fn) (which is a shortcut to $(document).ready ) to run after changing to other path, so it'll run this code on each path change.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am using turbolinks. I just know when I created my homecontroller It made a home.js in my assets/javascripts folder.

Comment: I wrapped my code in your block and it still not executing when i go back to the route.

Comment: Found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links